# PHP json_encode to Javascript undefined/null

Tags: php, javascript, json, zend-framework

I'm having an issue returning a JSON from PHP to Javascript. Below is my PHP to create the JSON:

```
$environment[] = array('id' => $env, 'adjacencies' => $hostnames);

foreach($hostnames as $hostname) {
        $environment[] = array('id' => $hostname, 'name' => $hostname, 'data' => array());
    }

return json_encode($environment);;
```

When I print the json_encode environment to a text file, it comes back as:

```
[{"id":"Dev","adjacencies":["tb23","tbwag","tbvg","tbut"]},{"id":"tb23","name":"tb23","data":[]},{"id":"tbwag","name":"tbwag","data":[]},{"id":"tbvg","name":"tbvg","data":[]},{"id":"tbut","name":"tbut","data":[]}]
```

It seems that this is printing out properly but when I return it to the Javascript its coming back as undefined/null. Below is the javascript with the ajax call:

```
var ajax = new AJAX();
var args = "id=" + $("#apps").val() + "&env=" + node.id + "&nocache=" + (new Date()).valueOf();
ajax.connect("POST", "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/project/graph/host", args, function(json) {

var output = '';
for (property in json) {
    output += property + ': ' + json[property]+'; ';
}
alert(output);
});
```

I've obviously tried a lot of different things to get it to print out but haven't had any luck. In PHP, I've tried json_last_error and it came back as '0', which means that there isn't an issue with the JSON structure.

In the end, I'd like to use the following command in Javascript to continue building my graph:

```
var hostNodes = eval('(' + json + ')');
```

Any help is appreciated as to why I can't get this to come back!

Comment: Where is $env and $hostnames? It's not there. I'll change my answer if you really just forgot to mention it and It's not the problem.

Comment: These variables are working fine so I left them out; they are created in another function. For all intensive purposes in this example, they can be hardcoded.

Comment: The PHP works fine, you're obviously doing some mistake in the javascript.

Comment: what is the actual value of json before you run your loop?

Comment: You need to use `JSON.parse(plainJsonText)` in JS to get that object in javascript because even when you encode the data server-side, it returns a plain string, which javascript considers a plain string only, not any special JSON thing. So, you'll need `JSON.parse` ...

Comment: How are you echoing the json_encoded values in php?

Comment: What do the alerts give you? Correct property names with null values, no property names, or what? Also, what library is the AJAX type from? Are you sure it's automatically parsing the HTTP response as JSON and passing the parsed JSON to the callback function? That would be rather odd (IMO) for a class called "AJAX" to assume that the result would be JSON and not, as the term AJAX indicates, XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your PHP code in an unique file that receives one post parameters, then construct the json array if it set, and at the bottom you can do

```
echo json_encode($json);
flush();
```

I'm not a professional with pure javascript and I'm not familar with your approach, but you should consider using jQuery, at least I'm going to suggest one way to receive an json array so that you can easily work with it (you also make sure that the data is json):

```
$.ajax(
{
    // Post select to url.
    type : 'post',
    url : 'myPHPAjaxHandler.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : 
    {
        'select' : true
    },
    success : function(data)
    {
        // PHP has returned a json array.

        var id, hostname;

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            id = data[i].id;
            hostname = hostname[i].id;
            // Construct a string or an object using the data.

        }
    },
    complete : function(data)
    {
        // Optional.
    }
});
```

Like I say, It's there for you to decide whether you pick it up or not. It can become handy for complex projects.

Comment: But you are using JQuery and he is not

Comment: I understand, maybe I should just delete this, or allow him to see this and maybe he'll decide to pick it up. We might say that I'm just suggesting a library within the same language as he is using.

Comment: Hey Jonast92, I tried your solution but it's coming up with 'length' is null or not an object. So it seems to me that data still isn't coming back with anything for some reason

Comment: How are you echoing the json_encoded values in php? Your function is returning the json_encoded values, but how are you printing them to the client?

Comment: If the length is null or not an object the array is either empty or you're not parsing through the inner array, it might happen that your returned data is actually another array, then you need to walk through that array like any other array. "How are you echoing the json_encoded values in php" : Once you do echo json_encode($json);
flush(); in the php which received your posted values, then the javascript knows that it is indeed the json array that is to be used.

Comment: Awesome, it did turn out to be another array so I used JSON.stringify to get what I needed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're assuming that the data passed to the callback function will be your JSON already parsed into JS objects, but I don't see any indication that that would be the case; it's most likely the raw JSON data that must be parsed into JS objects using JSON.parse (NOT eval() - eval() is very dangerous, you should always prefer JSON.parse when working with true JSON data, as it will not permit XSS-style attacks as they are generally not "pure" JSON.)